# How to validate hibernate lazy loading collection size?

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
Class MyModel {

    public interface ServerGroup {}
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 1, groups=ServerGroup.class)
    //@NotEmpty(groups=ServerGroup.class) // Tried this as well but not working!
    @OneToMany
    //@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) It works! Don't really want to do eager fetch
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();


  //getters and setters here
  .....
}


Class Mytest {

@Test
public void testMyModel
MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.setName("This is testing");
persist(myModel); //persisting to database

//Now loading back again from database
MyModel myModel = MyModel.Service.findMyModelByName("This is testing");
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyModel>> violations = validator.validate(myModel,ServerGroup.class);
Assert.assertEquals(1, violations.size()); //It fails here saying no violation
}
```

As you can see created and then loaded mymodel from database where persons is empty so try to run validate against ServerGroup 'group' but no violations and if I change that to eager loading then it works? Any suggestions please.

Comment: which version of hibernate you are using?

Comment: Hibernate version 4.1.4.Final and Hibernate Validation version 4.3.0.Final.

Comment: Can you also add the @NotEmpty annotation to the persons property to see what it do?

Comment: Question edited. Tried @NotEmpty(groups = ServerGroup.class). still not working!